# What is .htc file ?How it works in Internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I downloaded the .htc file and embedded in css to get the rounded corners in internet explorer 8.But i am wondering how it works

```
.curved {

-moz-border-radius:10px;

-webkit-border-radius:10px;

behavior:url(border-radius.htc);

}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's an [HTML Component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Components), a means of encapsulating logic on a web page. Behaviors were described in a [1999 w3 CSS working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-becss-19990804) but (as far as I know) only Microsoft provided an implementation in IE 5 and today there are better ways of accomplishing the same tasks.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018.aspx

HTCs should only be used as a fallback mechanism (which your example demonstrates). Most of what is possible with them is possible using standard, cross-browser CSS and JavaScript in IE 9 and higher.

As to *why* it works, my guess is that the behavior manipulates IE-specific functionality such as DHTML filters or [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) which can be used to achieve visual results that were ahead of their time (though now deprecated).

Answer (score -1):

*All browsers provide some way to look at a stylesheet's rules using javascript, and dynamically insert new rules. Normally, IE returns "unknown" for anything it does not support, for instance; a `div p:first-child` would change into `div p:unknown`, and a `p a[href]` would be returned as "UNKNOWN" altogether. Fortunately IE recognizes :hover as something it's familiar with, and leaves it alone.*

*IE also supports so called `behaviors`; both predefined functionality like dynamic content loading or persistent data storage, as well as custom behaviors that you can build into an .htc or .hta file. These behaviors are linked to html nodes via css, and "enhance" the nodes that are selected by a rule's selector with the given behavior.*

*Combining the above, it should be possible to create a bahavior that searches the styles for rules IE doens't support, and trick affected elements into applying the associated styles some other way. The steps involved in this are something like:*

*Search all stylesheets for :hover rules IE doesn't support,
Insert a new rule IE does support, like one with class names,
and finally, set up script events for switching class names.
This way, :hover, :active and :focus can be supported, and as a developer you don't have to do anything except including the behavior. Everything else runs on full automatic.*

*Unlike versions 1 and 2, version 3 also supports dynamically added html (ajax). The difference is that 1 and 2 actively searched for affected elements onload of the page (so; only once), whereas 3 uses expressions to let nodes do a callback themselves.*

You can read more about it [here](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html)