# background-size: cover not works fine in ie 8 & below even using -ms filter's

Tags: css

Am Trying to use my banner section with cover background it works fine with latest browser's.But struck on ie7 & 8

css is like

```
.banner {
  background: url("images/banner_bg.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/banner_bg.png'
,sizing   Method='scale');

 -ms-background-position-x:100% center;
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
  (src='images/banner_bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
     height: 297px;
    background-size: cover;
   }
```

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size: cover` is not supported in IE8 -- not even with an `-ms-` prefix. It simply hadn't been invented yet when IE8 was released.

If you need to use this feature, my suggestion is to use [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/). This is a polyfill script that adds support for this feature (and other CSS features) to old IE versions.

You may also want to see my answer to a similar question here: [I want the background picture not to be displayed in the IE. How do I do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645343/i-want-the-background-picture-not-to-be-displayed-in-the-ie-how-do-i-do-that/16647265#16647265)

Answer (score 4):

I've used http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/ in the past to give background cover/contain support to older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but this answer may help someone else:

Download [backgroundsize.min.htc](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill/downloads) and put it inside your project.

Now simply add these lines in your css:

```
.class_name{
    //your other properties
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-behavior: url(backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

**NOTE: use the `url` according to your project setup.**

Enjoy this simple solution. **:)**

Comment: What is `.htc` refers too.! how do i use it

Comment: Please note that here on Stack Overflow we do not post [duplicate answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275075/full-size-background-image-in-ie8/22003894#22003894). Instead flag a question as a duplicate if you really think it is one.

Comment: Hey Vivek, to use htc file just add downloded file in your project and set the url of that file in behavior attribute (in css file).  click on this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767006/what-is-htc-file-how-it-works-in-internet-explorer