# full size background image in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-image

I used this property in css but its not working in IE8

```
html{
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../../images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../../images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"; 
    }

body {
    background-image:url(../../images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    }
```

I got many solutions on stackoverflow but none of them worked.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>

#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: ya its worked but I need solution using background-image in body tag isn't it possible ?

Comment: yes but it will only work in IE8+, this is just a tweak to make it work in older versions of IE.

Comment: ya in other browser background-size is worked .
I am finding solution in ie8.

Comment: but in your solution my other images are hide.

Answer (score 3):

I made a Sass Mixin if this help anyone:

```
@mixin background-cover($cover-image){
  background: url($cover-image) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='#{$cover-image}', sizingMethod='scale')";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='#{$cover-image}', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

**Call it by using**

```
@include background-cover('/images/foo.png');
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but this answer may help someone else:

Download [backgroundsize.min.htc](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill/downloads) and put it inside your project.

Now simply add these lines in your css:

```
.class_name{
    //your other properties
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-behavior: url(backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

**NOTE: use the `url` according to your project setup.**

Enjoy this simple solution. **:)**

Answer (score 1):

I think generic tags should go after the browser-specific ones:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

and also:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../../images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../../images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
```

Hope this works.

Comment: You might need to clear your browser's cache and then refresh.

Comment: Have you tried any of this technique http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: yes i have tried all of technique from that,

its worked with img tag ("CSS-Only Technique #1"),
but is it possible by background image in body tag ?